# Silverlight 4 problems with FireFox 3.6?

Tags: firefox, silverlight-4.0

I just started making a Silverlight 4 application and added a button to it.

The button doesn't appear in FireFox though. Works fine in Chrome and IE.

Can't find anything specific on google but there seem to be some problems with FireFox 3.6.

Anyone know a work-around or solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont see anything you have to do the height issue  (setting the silverlight object to have a height (that isn't just 100%) should help

Comment: I have a height set on the button, <Button x:Name="Button" FontSize="16" Height="45" Width="150" /> Still not appearing in Firefox.

Comment: http://codebetter.com/blogs/peter.van.ooijen/archive/2008/12/18/silverlight-firefox-and-100.aspx

should give you a better explanation than I am